# auto-generate comment with a Python-Script

Tags: python, intellij-idea, plugins, comments, auto-generate

Is it possible to auto-generate java comments for the all java classes in IntelliJ IDEA with a Python-Script? Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: ```with open('... .java','w') as file:```, ```file.write("// This is a comment")```

Comment: You can use the JavaDoc plugin for generation JavaDoc comments in batch mode. It is the simplest way to do it. (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7157-javadoc/)